# WPF: Key trigger within Child control Popup is not working

Tags: wpf, popup, interaction

I have a user control which is placed inside a Popup. The user control has key triggers like below

```
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:KeyTrigger Key="Left" Modifiers="Ctrl" FiredOn="KeyDown" >
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=WindowSelectionKeyBackCommand}"  />
    </i:KeyTrigger>
    <i:KeyTrigger Key="Right" Modifiers="Ctrl" FiredOn="KeyDown">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=WindowSelectionKeyNextCommand}" />
    </i:KeyTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

But these triggers don't execute on the key press.

Comment: In order to get a useful answer, you should post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In your sample, it is unclear in which context the code is used, what the data context is or where the bound propreties for the commands are defined.

Comment: What's the `DataContext` of the user control and where are the commands defined?